# Skipping first String Input when I am giving data in Console

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a program that will read user inputs and will printout them gradually. But when I am running the code, in the Console area, the first line is automatically skipping. But when I am taking input as Integer, all is running well. Where is my fault?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MainClass {
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int limit, i, j;
        System.out.print("How many names you want to take: ");
        limit = input.nextInt();
        String[] name = new String[limit];

        for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
            name[i] = input.nextLine();
        }

        for (String output : name) {
            System.out.println("Names are: " + output);
        }

    }
}
```

Console area:

```
How many names you want to take: 3
Enter your name: Enter your name: Saon
Enter your name: Srabon
Names are: 
Names are: Saon
Names are: Srabon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `input.nextLine()` after the `input.nextInt()` in order to clear the `new line` character produced by pressing Enter key (when you enter int number);

Alternatively, you can read your `int` as `Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine())`.

Comment: or use the "thank you" button